# LocalStorage with Json.stringify not persisting

Tags: json, local-storage, stringify

In it's simplest form:

```
localStorage.setItem('index0', JSON.stringify(playerInventory[lootArray[0]]));

var retrievedIndex0 = localStorage.getItem('index0');
console.log('retrieved0:'+retrievedIndex0 );  //Displays correct amount
```

So I thought it was working, but then if I don't setItem immediately before using getItem, it returns null, or if I setItem, hit F5, 'index0' becomes null...

```
if(localStorage.getItem('index0') <  playerInventory[lootArray[0]]) { 
console.log('bingo! '); 
localStorage.setItem('index0', JSON.stringify(playerInventory[lootArray[0]])); }
```

This ^ will output 'bingo!' into the log (in firefox), but the setItem does not update localStorage. If I replay the game it'll be null if I don't setItem again before getItem...

This will fire correctly as well...

```
var oldscore = localStorage.getItem('index0');
var newscore = playerInventory[lootArray[0]]; 
if(oldscore < newscore) { console.log('new high score');}
```

But setItem will not update localStorage....and if I hit f5 and replay the game it'll be null

```
if(oldscore < newscore) { 
console.log('new high score'); //This fires

localStorage.setItem('index0', JSON.stringify(playerInventory[lootArray[0]])); //this doesnt
}
```

if I go to my main update() loop, and put:

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem('index0')); //returns null
console.log(localStorage.getItem.index0);  //returns undefined
```

Anyone see anything wrong, or have any other tests I could do?

playerInventory[lootArray[0]] is holding the number that I want to use compare with localstorage and update to localstorage when it's higher....I use that object to update divs on my screen with the current value so I know it's holding the integer that I want to save/restore.................................

**I just tested in IE and it doesn't work at all it errors:** Even the basic first part at the top of this post throws the error.

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'getItem': object is
>   null or undefined

I can set the item in the same function before using getItem and it's not null obviously at that moment but it doesn't persist beyond that point......

Answer (score 0):

I was having similiar issues with this error when I was working on a project.  I've noticed that when I attempted to just run my file, I would keep getting the error of being null or undefined.  Once I put my project on a server, it worked.

Also, you already have a variable for the retrieved index.  Try using that for your checks, then, if the score is higher, set the new score, if not, set the retrieved index back into local storage.

A note for IE, if you're getting errors when trying to getItem, IE won't go pass the errors in the current method/function.  When trying to getItem in IE, throw a try catch around it. 
I hope this can help.

Also, try using

```
localStorage.setItem('index0', JSON.stringify(newscore));
```

since you already have the variable created.